# Do values like ping/download rate give reasonable validation on router <---> radio mast connection strength?

Tags: router

we receive our "Internet signal" form a radio mast (i don't know exactly if its LTE or sth else..), because of the current location of our router, the signal has to go through some walls.

Basically, we want to measure how much the Internet connection improves when we move our router to a "non-blocked" location.

==> My Question is what values i should expect to improve/change. I'm not sure if the ping or my download/upload rate will increase, therefore I'm wondering if [e.g. this site](http://testmy.net/) can measure the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The far away the router is from the internet source point, the higher ping and lower download/upload rate you will have, you'll probably have more packet loss because of this too.

In this case, you can compare as if you were using your mobile on low cell bars/higher density of people using it at the same time.

Comment: Are you suggesting that moving the router a few meters will make a noticeable difference reagrding the time the radio waves need, and that you lose packets when you don't have full signal strength? -- I think I'll support the bandwith point. Better signal strenght, better negotiated bandwidth.

Comment: OP mentioned multiple walls, i assume there might be interferences within them, which will 'cause you to probably lose packets at times, you're always prone to lose packets/drop connections in any wireless connection, specially if you're far from the router and the server timeouts aren't that great.